# Redirect not working with Thymeleaf in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, thymeleaf

I'am trying to create a simple app on Spring Boot:
Controller:

```
 @Controller
 public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping ("/")
    public String root() {
         return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/joinChart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String joinChart(@RequestParam (defaultValue = "") String username) {
          return "redirect:chat?username=" + username;
    }
 }
```

root-method is working well. But when I try to redirect on login-page, it return 404-ERROR.

[image: project]

Comment: Do you have a request mapping for `/login`?

Comment: No, in login.html  I  realise get-request  on "/joinChart?username=somename".

Comment: sorry, I have a mistake: not return "redirect:login...", but "redirect:chat...".

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
return "login";
```

in your `root()` handler method, you're actually just returning a view name (typically handled by a [`JstlView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html) but here handled by [`ThymeleafView`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring4/3.0.0.BETA03/org/thymeleaf/spring4/view/ThymeleafView.html) since you're using Thymeleaf), but  that Spring MVC's web infrastructure (with your Servlet web container) will try to find and render.

When you do

```
return "redirect:chat?username=" + username;
```

in your `joinChart` handler method, you're actually returning a [*redirect* view name](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) that the server will render as a 303 response with a `Location` header. The client will be instructed to send a new request to `/chat`. If you don't have a request mapping for that, obviously the server will return a 404.

You need to add a request mapping for `/chat`

```
@RequestMapping ("/chat")
public String chat() {
     return "chat";
}
```